# Azure DocumentDB paging with stored procedure?

Tags: azure, paging, azure-cosmosdb

However DocumentDB query is not supporting to get count and order by functions.
We can write stored procedure  to get working the orderby and count functions.

DocumentDB supporting paging concept with continuation token.

Can We implement a stored procedure to get fully paging concept in terms of getting records by index and no of records?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly possible to implement paging on your own by iterating through query results; however I would exercise caution if you are looking to implement this via stored procedure - as the script will be fairly costly in terms of RUs. Keep in mind stored procedures have bounded execution; you will need to implement your own continuation model.

Please vote for paging on DocumentDB's user voice to help get this feature prioritized:
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6350987--documentdb-allow-paging-skip-take